# What is the appropriate way to store geospatial data in MongoDB?

Tags: geojson, mongodb, schema

I'm in the process of planning my MongoDB schema for a MEAN stack web app that will deal with a lot of geospatial data. Points, polylines, etc. I've been boning up on the GeoJSON spec. One of my primary concerns is interoperability of the datasets I'm producing and that of various GIS clients, mapping APIs and so on. I want to make sure I have a sustainable schema that doesn't require a lot of massaging to use in various applications.

Please help me understand one thing. MongoDB claims to support "GeoJSON objects", but when I look at the requirements/suggested schema they specify it differs significantly from the actual GeoJSON spec.

So, for example, the GeoJSON spec calls for something like:

```
{
 "type": "Feature",
 "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
 },
 "properties": {
      "name": "Dinagat Islands"
 }
}
```

Whereas, following the MongoDB/Mongoose documentation it would be represented like:

```
{
 "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  location: {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  }
}
```

Obviously the later is more efficient, but when GeoJSON has such a rigid spec what's the point of following the MongoDB way and constantly transforming the data to actual GeoJSON schema and then back to the Mongo Schema as needed?

Also, why is MongoDB claiming they allow use of GeoJSON when they're so clearly not following the actual spec? Should I just accept their "way" and move on?

Comment: if interoperability is a concern use an established server like GeoServer to control access to your database (even Mongo if you must) and to talk to all the clients out there

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm not too interested in adding Java to my implementation, having already built a large portion of my backend in Node. I'm more looking for best practices around how geospatial data can be stored in MongoDB, and if there are any limitations.